# calling wcf service from jquery ajax - getting exception - incoming request is not allowed

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, jsonp

Exception details:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.Web.dll
>   Additional information: The HTTP method 'GET' of the incoming request (with URI http://localhost:24342/Test.svc/DoWork?callback=jQuery110203769165082986856_1479380612393&testParameter=TEST&_=1479380612394) is not allowed.

I am using Ajax-embedded WCF service. WCF client is a jQuery Ajax call. My code:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "testWCFAjax")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Service
{       
    [OperationContract]
    [System.ServiceModel.Web.WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
       RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json )]         
    public string DoWork(string testParameter)
    {            
        return "success";
    }
}
```

Web Config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
                <enableWebScript/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
        <services>
            <service name="Service">
                <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Service"/>
        </service>
    </services>    
</system.serviceModel>
```

Ajax Code:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CallMyService() {
        $.support.cors = true;
        var param = '{"testParameter": "TEST"}';
        $.ajax({  
            url: 'http://localhost:24342/Test.svc/DoWork',
            data: param,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "jsonp",                
            contentType: "application/json",                
            success: ServiceSucceeded,
            error: ServiceFailed
        });
    }
```

Comment: for starters that should be `var param = {"testParameter": "TEST"};` (without quotes). It will serialise the anonymous object for you.

Comment: hi @GoneCoding - I did that but still getting the same exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by creating WCF service with Ajax-embedded.